# One SQL Schema per user

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

The database administrator on the project we have has decided that each user must have 1 SQL server schema per user. That mean that if the system does have 20k users that the Sql Server will have 20k schema. The reason is for security.

So far, no problem, but since we are using Entity Framework and that the Schema is set at startup when the Database Context is initialized, we cannot change the schema.

My question is divided in two:

1. Is it a good way to proceed to have 1 schema per user?
2. How can I handle this situation with Entity Framework?

We are using C# with .Net 4.0 on Asp.Mvc with Sql Server 2008 R2 and EF4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Schemas, introduced in SQL Server 2005, offer a convenient way to separate database users from database object owners.

Now I think that creating one schema for each user it could be too much as you could have users that have different schema but owners of the same object.

I think it could be enough to have maybe few several different schema( divide up areas of responsibility or logical grouping eg (Data and Staging schemas for our tables)) to have a more granular object ownership management

more info at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095%28SQL.100%29.aspx

regarding using different schemas with EF refer to

[SQL Server "User-Schema Separation" and Entity Framework issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466120/sql-server-user-schema-separation-and-entity-framework-issues)

Comment: Thank you for your input about SQL schema. I will read the linked you provided carefully.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems silly, and a lot of hassle, to use a different schema for each user. Especially if you really are heading towards 20K users.

I'm pretty sure that between SQL Server and ASP.NET MVC you could implement a secure solution without doing this.

Just my 2 cents :)

I think that the [Entity Framework Runtime Model Adapter](http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/) should be able to help you solve your problem regarding changing the schema.

> A set of Entity Framework connection and model adapters, allowing the
>   arbitrary adjustment of an ObjectContext model at runtime.
>
> This project allows a developer to adjust an Entity Framework schema
>   at runtime when the deployment and development environments differ.

Comment: I'll give a look soon to this RuntTime Model Adapter if it works well with Code First (poco) approach. Thanks

Comment: @codingbadger, realise this is an old post but how would you suggest achieving this? "I'm pretty sure that between SQL Server and ASP.NET MVC you could implement a secure solution without doing this."